# Change dropdown popup height in Kendo for Angular

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In this [StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhxbu7) I have a Kendo for Angular dropdown list. When you open the dropdown, the popup shows seven items. I just want to show three items. So I set the height in `popupSettings` to 30, but Kendo is ignoring it. How to change the popup height?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <kendo-dropdownlist 
         [data]="listItems"
         [popupSettings]="{
            width: 100,
            height: 30 }">
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public listItems: Array<string> = [];

    ngOnInit(){
         for(var i=1;i<=100;i++)
            this.listItems.push('Item ' + i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/popupsettings-height-doesn%27t-work).  You have to set the [`listHeight`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/AutoCompleteComponent/#toc-listheight) property.

```js
<kendo-dropdownlist 
    [data]="listItems"
    [popupSettings]="{
        width: 100,
        height: 30 }" 
    [listHeight]="500">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will see Kendo generate a `div` for the dropdown if you can inspect the elements on your browser.

```
<div unselectable="on" class="k-list-scroller" style="max-height: 200px;">
```

Change the `max-height` for class `k-list-scroller`

Comment: Please see this [StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhxbu7-ncq1o2), changing k-list-scroller didn't work